# How to install operating system on vcenter with ansible?

Tags: ansible, vmware, vcenter

I'm creating a new vm with ansible. I used vmware_guest here. I have added the iso file when creating vm. After creating, I turned on the power. But I can't intervene to install the operating system.

**How can I install the new vm operating system (linux, windows) that I created with Ansible?**

```
> - name: Create a virtual machine
>       vmware_guest:
>         hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
>         username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
>         password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
>         datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
>         validate_certs: no
>         folder: /Ansible-Test
>         name: "{{vm_name}}"
>         state: poweredon
>         guest_id: "{{isletim_sistemi}}"
>         cluster: CLUSTER
>         disk:
>         - size_gb: "{{disk_boyutu}}"
>           type: eagerzeroedthick
>           autoselect_datastore: true
>         hardware:
>           memory_mb: "{{ram}}"
>           num_cpus: "{{cpu}}"
>           scsi: paravirtual
>         cdrom:
>           type: iso
>           iso_path: "{{iso}}"
>         networks:
>         - name: "{{vlan}}"
>           device_type: vmxnet3
>         wait_for_ip_address: no
>       delegate_to: localhost
>       register: deploy_vm
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONpik.png)

**The picture above shows the result of creating vm. I want to install the operating system by interfering with the next section.**

I want to install centos 7, but I cannot intervene in the installation process.
Is this possible?
I want to work with this method, not with the template. I am familiar with creating templates.

```
ansible 2.7.10
Pyvmomi
vsphere 6.7
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom ISO file for the operating system. Eg. Binding kickstart file with RHEL operating system so that there will not be able to manual intervention during the booting process.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible can do that from a template, which you seem to already be familiar with, but I'm not aware of any methods which would allow you to build a VM from scratch.